# Wildcards in SQL Server full text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

While figuring out with full-text search I've found [an article](https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-full-text-search-for-symbols-in-SQL-Server):

> FTS differentiates between a symbol defined as a wildcard and the
> other symbols. Here are a few symbols used in FTS as wildcards:

```
+==================================+========+==============================================================================================================================================================================================================+
|            Expression            | Syntax |                                                                                                 Description                                                                                                  |
+==================================+========+==============================================================================================================================================================================================================+
| Any Character                    | .      | Matches any single character except a line break.                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Zero or more                     | *      | Matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding expression, making all possible matches.                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| One or more                      | +      | Matches at least one occurrence of the preceding expression.                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Beginning of line                | ^      | Anchors the match string to the beginning of a line                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| End of line                      | $      | Anchors the match string to the end of a line.                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Beginning of word                | <      | Matches only when a word begins at this point in the text.                                                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| End of word                      | >      | Matches only when a word ends at this point in the text.                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Line break                       | \n     | Matches a platform-independent line break. In a Replace expression, inserts a line break.                                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Any one character in the set     | [ ]    | Matches any one of the characters within the [ ]. To specify a range of characters, list the starting and ending character separated by a dash (-), as in [a-z].                                             |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Any one character not in the set | [^...] | Matches any character not in the set of characters following the ^.                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Or                               | |      | Matches either the expression before or the one after the OR symbol (|). Mostly used within a group. For example, (sponge|mud) bath matches "sponge bath" and "mud bath."                                    |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Escape                           | \      | Matches the character that follows the backslash (\) as a literal. This allows you to find the characters used in regular expression notation, such as { and ^. For example, ^ Searches for the ^ character. |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tagged expression                | {}     | Matches text tagged with the enclosed expression.                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| C/C++ Identifier                 | :i     | Matches the expression ([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*).                                                                                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Quoted string                    | :q     | Matches the expression (("[^"]*")|('[^']*')).                                                                                                                                                                |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Space or Tab                     | :b     | Matches either space or tab characters.                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Integer                          | :z     | Matches the expression ([0-9]+).                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

But I cannot find any info about that possibilities and usage (except `*` off course). Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that all these symbols are supported.
The list of symbols is probably taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-2017). But this documents SQL Server Mamagement Studio (SSMS) functionality.

The only Symbol which is supported is a asterisk (*) at the end of a word. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), search for `<prefix term>` on this page.